# Swift, present a new uiview with tab bar

Tags: swift, tabbar, uitabcontroller

I am trying to present a new view after click button in a tableview cell. The view can show up but without the tab bar. Is there any solution that showing the view with tab bar? Thanks.

[Storyboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0MSn.png)

Using segue or progammatically are not right.

```
  func viewDetailAction(sender: UIButton){
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("patientDetailVC    ") as! PatientDetailViewController
  //        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
 //        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("patientDetailCell", sender: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A easier way is to present the VC yourself

```
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

This will present it on your current VC and not on the tab barController as it is being done probably in the storyboard segue

Please ignore any code syntax mistakes.

Comment: I have tried that way, but it is not working. Still get the view without bottom tab bar

Comment: your comments in code show you used self.present and not self.tabBarController.present

Comment: Thank you man.        self.tabBarController?.presentViewController(vc, animated:true, completion:nil). it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
```

after **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier**.

> **Edit:** (using segue)

Simply, delete show segue and use **Present Modally** segue, click on segue, be sure **Over Current Context** presentation.

And then use in your action only:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("overNewPage", sender: nil)
```

You can reach its properties using **prepareForSegue** method.

[image]

> **Edit:** (using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier)

```
        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("patientDetailVC") as! PatientDetailViewController
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
        viewController.someString = "youCanPassData"

        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: vc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil),,,not working :(

Comment: @JaniceZhan Updated my answer.

Comment: I followed your step but still not working. It sucks!

Comment: @JaniceZhan There are two different way to do it, you are doing something wrong. Make sure your Storyboard ID is correct for second path. They work with me.

Comment: @JaniceZhan For first path, please connect your segue from ViewController, not directly from your button. If you prefer doing directly, you don't need to use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("overNewPage", sender: nil)`.

Comment: @JaniceZhan For directly segue, make sure you deleted your own action from Connection Inspector.